# Why cant I write "nwe" or "nwo" in excel cell?

Tags: excel

If I write **nwe** and **nwo** in a cell in excel with general or text as cell format, It updates it to **new** and **now**

Does anybody know why so? And Whats the solution?

Comment: This question would be better asked on Superusers as this is not a programming related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is an autocorrect behavior. It is customizable, as shown in the screenshow below:

[image]

Comment: So if update my excel auto-correct settings Will it affect same thing in some1 else's computer? If I share same excel file?

Comment: @KuldeepDaftary These settings apply only to your installation. If you enter `nwe` it will still appear as `nwe` on their machine. The AutoCorrect will only kick in if the other person has it enabled and enters one of the affected values himself or herself.

Answer (score 3):

The AutoCorrect option are enabled.

You can change it from

```
File -> Options -> Proofing -> Auto Correct Options -> Replace text as you type
```

Comment: Or press Undo (`Ctrl-z`) after the auto correct.

Comment: Yes, we can use Undo but only for word followed by space. For one word, pressing Undo will delete the cell.

Comment: Good point. I didn't realize that if that's your only word in the cell it wouldn't just revert to what you typed. That's mildly annoying.